# Battery notifications stopped working after upgrade to 19.10

Tags: battery, notification, 19.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 and my battery notifications don't seem to be working. I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I would like to fix it.

Update: After several sessions, my notifications do appear to be broken. How do I fix this?